# Why is column sort not retained when navigating to another page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

The new [search interface for job listings](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs) does allow to sort by column via their respective header as one would expect. However, the column sort is not retained when navigating to another page, be it via 'next' or a direct page number link.

---

While looking into this it might make sense to consider the following related questions too, together they might be considered to be a user story 'sort by column':

- [Why are columns only sortable in
  ascending order?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/why-are-columns-only-sortable-in-ascending-order)
- [Why is there no
  visual indication of column sort
  order?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54810/why-is-there-no-visual-indication-of-column-sort-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Steffen, this should be resolved. Thanks for the heads-up!