# Why are columns only sortable in ascending order?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, search, user-experience

**Update:**

This question didn't get any ACK whatsoever by the responsible Stack Overflow team, [despite them asking users for feedback explicitly](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/careers-now-more-awesomer/) in the first place:

> keep the feedback coming in the [careers] tag on meta.stackoverflow.com!

Yeah, right, glad to help you with my time ...

Unfortunately this lack of response is still happening way too often and I have to say that, as unimportant as the topic at hand may be, this definitely discourages participation on Meta in general and filing issues against this kind of 'pseudo-tracker' in particular, even more so, if users are specifically asked for feedback like here.

Anyway, the respective column sort UI has been replaced by a less powerful one in the meantime, so this [`feature-request`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) can be marked `status-obsolete` by now.

---

**Original:**

The new [search interface for job listings](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs) does allow to sort by column via their respective header as one would expect. However, another user expectation is that one can always toggle the sort order from ascending to descending by another click.

Admittedly one can usually reach the desired location by going to the last page in ascending order and walk backwards, but I'd argue this to be both counter intuitive and harder to navigate from the perspective of [User experience (UX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience).

So obviously this is not very important, but would be a nice improvement.

---

While looking into this it might make sense to consider the following related questions too, together they might be considered to be a user story 'sort by column':

- [Why is column sort not retained when navigating to another page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/why-is-column-sort-not-retained-when-navigating-to-another-page)
- [Why is there no
  visual indication of column sort
  order?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54810/why-is-there-no-visual-indication-of-column-sort-order)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Steffen,

As you have already mentioned there is now a new sort mechanism in place.

Initially I found the sort in SE sites confusing. What you can do, once you have chosen which sort you want to do, go to the bottom of the page and you will see a bunch of page numbers like:

1 2 3 4 5 ... 18

Simply click on the 18 and go backwards through the listings. This is the way it works on all the SE sites.

It's not 100% elegant, because you always have to return to the bottom of the page, but it still serves its purpose.

In regards to attention a question gets that is all down to the community, that's the way the world works, if people feel they are having the same problem they will give it the attention it deserves. Otherwise they will just ignore it.

Comment: I'm aware of this workaround, thanks for explaining it properly though (+1) - to me this is an unfortunate step back, because the previous UI could have been much more powerful (if implemented thoroughly, i.e. with all these features ;)

Comment: Re attention: you are right here as well in principle, but please notice that I'm addressing a case, where the Stack Exchange team, which is getting paid to support their product, explicitly asked the community for feedback and doesn't even take the time to acknowledge it (i.e status declined, deferred, planned or so) - asking users for their time without a commitment to react is impolite at best, though likely (and unfortunately) it's more lack of professionalism than anything else: if they'd use this pseudo 'issue-tracker' properly, they'd want to clear issue queues regularly at least.