# Why is there no visual indication of column sort order?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, search, user-experience

**Update:**

This question didn't get any ACK whatsoever by the responsible Stack Overflow team, [despite them asking users for feedback explicitly in the first place](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/careers-now-more-awesomer/):

> keep the feedback coming in the [careers] tag on meta.stackoverflow.com!

Yeah, right, glad to help you with my time ...

Unfortunately this lack of response is still happening way too often and I have to say that, as unimportant as the topic at hand may be, this definitely discourages participation on Meta in general and filing issues against this kind of 'pseudo-tracker' in particular, even more so, if users are specifically asked for feedback like here.

Anyway, the respective column sort UI has been replaced by a less powerful one in the meantime, so this [`feature-request`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) can be marked `status-obsolete` by now.

---

**Original:**

The new [search interface for job listings](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs) does allow to sort by column via their respective header as one would expect. However, another user expectation is that one can always see directly which column is currently sorted (as well as in which order, in case it gets implemented, see my related feature request [Why are columns only sortable in ascending order?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/why-are-columns-only-sortable-in-ascending-order).

Admittedly one can usually infer the sorted column (as well as the sort order in case) by simply looking at the results close enough, but this is an unnecessary effort from the perspective of [User experience (UX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience).

So obviously this is not very important, but would be a nice improvement.

---

While looking into this it might make sense to consider the following related questions too, together they might be considered to be a user story 'sort by column':

- [Why are columns only sortable in ascending order?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/why-are-columns-only-sortable-in-ascending-order)
- [Why is column sort not retained when navigating to another page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/why-is-column-sort-not-retained-when-navigating-to-another-page)